# Filter recent entries in emacs dashboard

Tags: emacs

When using `dashboard` (https://melpa.org/#/dashboard) in emacs, how can I set it up so that it ignores directories or filenames matching a pattern like `.gitignore` ?

For example by default it shows `~/.emacs.d/elpa/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid plugins. Help on opensource plugins is minimal if you are not comfortable with developer jargon, politics and technical skills to understand the source code.

Just wait and see for yourselves - the emacs tag has 5.4K watchers, on average you get about <20 views per question, when do you think the question will be answered ?

Semantics aside, the suggestion is to just use the built in bookmarks feature. 
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html#Bookmarks

Comment: So this is not the "very friendly emacs community" they talk about in emacs videos on the internet ?

Comment: ~G Glassholes to be precise.. They will do anything for a penny. Penny-wise Penny Dreadful.

Answer (score 1):

The emacs community is friendly... but probably not as helpful as they could be. You could try filing a GitHub issue with the dashboard developer (here: https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard/issues). If you ever did figure out a fix for your own issue, I bet the dashboard maintainer would be glad to hear about it.